# JSON Conversion Object having same name as Array in separate record

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am trying to parse the below JSON using retrofit. Here JSON object is having same name as JSON Array. Is there a way to correctly create pojo's

Here button is an Object in first record whereas in the second record it is an Array.

Is this valid as per JSON specification.

```
{
    "Single": [{
        "button": {
            "target": "https://m.jjj.com",
            "title": "Shop Now"
        },
        "description": "W1",
        "image": "http://dojo.scene11.com/is/image/anf/anf-US-20150629",
        "title": "Sports at $25"
    }, {
        "button": [{
            "target": "https://m.abz.com",
            "title": "Shop Now"
        }],
        "description": "Good",
        "image": "http://axys.com.m/is/image/brands",
        "title": "gebra "
    }]
}
```

Comment: It's definitely valid JSON.

Comment: Why do you have to give same name to both?

Comment: You can create POJO's from this link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid JSON as per JSON specifications, but as we know an Array must have same type of values, you are violating that logic. So when you would be trying to directly map this JSON to the Java Object, it might give an exception, but in case you have written a custom parser, you might be able to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is valid if you are using proper function to parse your json. There can be json object and json array of same 'name'. 
But there should not be **two objects of same name**, or **two arrays of same name**. Even this will be valid json having two object(or array) of same name, but you will be able to get only one json object(or array) while parsing your json.